# Group Report With Header and Detail?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table transactions with below details

| id | dt_trans | category | description | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-05 | Expense | Food | 60.00 |
| 2 | 2022-08-05 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |
| 2 | 2022-08-08 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |

then I want to create report based on below report

|  | dt_trans | category | description | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Expense** |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2022-08-05 | Expense | Food | 60.00 |
|  |  |  | **Total** | 60.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| **Travel** |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2022-08-05 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |
| 2 | 2022-08-08 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |
|  |  |  | **Total** | 40.00 |

Usually I will create a temporary table based on the report and add the row based on 2 queries.
Here's the logic

```
Loop // query1 retrieve all the category

   query2 retrieve all the details based on category

end of loop query1
```

Is there a more simple way to create this report?

query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transaction`;
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cashaccount_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt_trans` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 income 1 expense',
  `amount` float(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00,
  `dt_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO `transaction` (`id`, `cashaccount_id`, `dt_trans`, `category`, `description`, `type`, `amount`, `dt_created`, `uid`) VALUES
(115, 1, '2021-10-10', 'Expense', 'Food', 1, 60.00, '2021-10-10 17:06:36', 1),
(121, 1, '2021-10-15', 'Travel', 'Petrol', 1, 20.00, '2021-10-15 01:01:15', 1),
(123, 1, '2021-10-05', 'Travel', 'Petrol', 0, 20.00, '2021-10-15 09:11:28', 1)
```

Comment: I think the efficient way is to use your backend language to write a function that accept `category`, then get the result and pass it to the table with their sum as well.

Comment: Yes, we can use backend to create this, but we wanna try the report directly from the query if possible, so no extra code from backend. the query result will present same like the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use ROLLUP. Example

```
select category head,rn, max(dt_trans)dt_trans,category,max(description)description,sum(amount) amount
from(
select *
  ,row_number()over(partition by category order by category desc,dt_trans) rn
from transaction
) t
group by category ,rn with rollup
```

Result. There null in rn - totals by category, null in both head and rn - report totals.

| head | rn | dt_trans | category | description | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Expense | 1 | 2021-10-10 | Expense | Food | 60.00 |
| Expense | null | 2021-10-10 | Expense | Food | 60.00 |
| Travel | 1 | 2021-10-05 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |
| Travel | 2 | 2021-10-15 | Travel | Petrol | 20.00 |
| Travel | null | 2021-10-15 | Travel | Petrol | 40.00 |
| null | null | 2021-10-15 | null | Petrol | 100.00 |

Answer (score 1):

Try to union three select statements with a specific order for each one as the following:

To get the report for all users:

```
with t as
(
  select id, dt_trans, category, description, amount, uid,
       dense_rank() over (order by uid, category) as ord1, 2 as ord2
  from transaction
  
  union all
  
  select distinct category, '', '', '', '', uid,
         dense_rank() over (order by uid, category) as ord1,
         1 as ord2
  from transaction 
  
  union all
  
  select  '', '', '', 'Total', 
          sum(amount), uid,
          dense_rank() over (order by uid, category) as ord1, 
          3 as ord2 
  from transaction 
  group by category, uid
)
select uid, id, dt_trans, category, description, amount
from t
order by uid, ord1, ord2
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0WbdZCVP)

To get the report for a single user:

```
with t as
(
  select id, dt_trans, category, description, amount,
       dense_rank() over (order by category) as ord1, 2 as ord2
  from transaction where uid = 1
  
  union all
  
  select distinct category, '', '', '', '',
         dense_rank() over (order by category) as ord1,
         1 as ord2
  from transaction where uid = 1
  
  union all
  
  select  '', '', '', 'Total', 
          sum(amount),
          dense_rank() over (order by category) as ord1, 
          3 as ord2 
  from transaction where uid = 1
  group by category 
)
select id, dt_trans, category, description, amount
from t
order by ord1, ord2
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LkRJ9d7_)

But it would be better to perform this kind of formatting reports outside the SQL server.

Comment: category is not fix only 2, it's dynamic data depend on the user

Comment: do you want to show this report for all users at once or for a single user on each run?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to loop on programming side but here is a simple mysql query

```
SELECT 
    s.*
FROM
    transaction s
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        category
    FROM
        transaction) AS t
        GROUP BY s.id
```

Comment: from where this new_table coming from?